# Edit Sync Object to the Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder

Is it possible to edit a Salesforce object which is already in Sync in the Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the fields to be synced (ie adding or deleting them ) but you cannot edit the data extension. A work around would be to copy with a query into a data extension then edit that

Comment: Changing a field type or its properties requires a slightly more complicated process, which might be a bit hazardous in a live environment: 1. Make your field adjustments. 2. Unsync the field in contact builder. 3. Clear data in the synchronized data extension. 4. Add the field again to push through your field update. So, do some careful planning (e.g. field dependencies in your MC processes) when you have to do this